# How to suppress printing to console?

Tags: julia

I'm using a non standard module in Julia, created by someone else.

Due to user restrictions I cannot modify this module.

The module prints the step it is currently executing to the console.

My console is full of excess information.

**Question:** Is there a way to suppress the console printing without modifying the module code?

Comment: Usually there's an option in the solver to reduce printing. Did you check the docs? Which package? Also, you can use Surpressor.jl's macros.

Comment: I think there is small typo in Chris's comment... [Suppressor.jl](https://github.com/Ismael-VC/Suppressor.jl)

Comment: you can also consider using `redirect_stdout` and `redirect_stderr` functions directly.

Comment: @Chris The module has almost no documentation, it is given in a paper and to use it they give some example files that work.

Comment: @FranciscoJoseRomeroHinrichs if the project is hosted on GitHub, please submit an issue. It is always nice to give feedback to the authors.

Comment: I never thought about it, I'll do it, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To  suppress the output of a function `foo`:

```
oldstd = stdout
redirect_stdout(devnull)
foo()
redirect_stdout(oldstd) # recover original stdout
```

If foo doesn’t have arguments one can also use `redirect_stdout(foo, devnull)`

However it works on my Linux box, but I am not 100% sure it works on Windows too..